# Page template option missing

Tags: templates, page-template

I checked everything suggested in [that response](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184104/page-editor-missing-templates-drop-down): "page attributes" option is checked, template file is located at theme root folder, I tried several file encoding options in my text editor (UTF8 with or without BOM), I tried switching to another theme then back to my custom theme, I do have the right stuff on top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Page Actualites
*/
?>
```

Why am I still not seeing the page template dropdown list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page was set as the posts page in `settings > reading`, which prevents from chosing a specific page template since this setting automatically assigns `index.php` as the page template for that page.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue when I reinstalled wordpress, realized I haven't activated the theme on which my templates are.

**So make sure you enabled your theme.**

Gosh, i forget this everytime :x

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) of the feature is really good. So check them, especially the name of the file, also the rights of the file via FTP or ssh - is it readable.

Do not use `page-` as a prefix, as WordPress will interpret the file as a specialized template, meant to apply to only one page on your site.

Remove also the PHP close tag, not necessary and often more problematic.

Comment: My template file is now named `actualites.php`, I have `<?php /* Template Name: Actualites */ ?>` on top, before that I tried to remove PHP tags. There's no FTP issue because that's my local machine server, but yes everybody on my machine can read the file in terms of permission. Still nothing :|

Comment: You should add them to the question, so is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress 5.8 introduced template editor: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2021/06/16/introducing-the-template-editor-in-wordpress-5-8/

Answer (score 0):

For me, my theme was missing the default `style.css` file, Once I added that, I could see the page template dropdown again. Using the Classic Editor plugin.